# Installing NuGet package Owin, get reference error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nuget, nuget-package, episerver

I'm trying to install the NuGet package [Owin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin/), but NuGet gives me this error:

`Already referencing a newer version of 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation'..`

This is wierd, and has to come from somewhere else, because Owin doesn't have any dependecies. As it turns out, this happens with other packages as well.

This is an ASP.NET MVC 5 project that uses EPiServer as a CMS with

Do anyone know what this is?

EDIT: As  it turns out, I only get this error in VS 2015 RC with Package Manager Console Host Version 3.0.0.0. I'll report it as a bug.

EDIT 2: Just posting the error message from NuGet:

```
Install-Package : Already referencing a newer version of 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation'..
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Owin
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: Can you throw `Install-Package Owin` command into the `Package Manager Console` and copy/paste the whole output here?

Comment: @JaniHyytiäinen Added the error message, but I solved it. See my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how much of a useful answer this is; but I solved it by using Visual Studio 2012 and Package Manager Console Host Version 2.8.50126.400. I would have used VS2013, but I don't have it installed. It seems the bug was only in VS 2015 RC with Package Manager Console Host Version 3.0.0.0.

I did report it as an issue in the issue tracker at the NuGet repository on GitHub.